# npm in docker crashes on local modules install

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, npm-install

I have forked `https://github.com/HugoDF/express-postgres-starter`, added some local modules and got to the codebase you can get here in order to reproduce the issue `https://giordanoarman@bitbucket.org/giordanoarman/docker-issue.git`.

I cannot install local modules and apparently third party modules don't get installed either.

I tried to look into the `docker-compose.yaml` configuration to see if something was wrong there, but I haven't found errors. It might be that I am a noob in docker and docker-compose so I may be missing something.

When I run `docker-compose up` it fails like this:

```
me@thepc:~/thepath$ docker-compose up
Starting express-postgres-starter_postgres_1 ... done
Starting express-postgres-starter_app_1      ... done
Attaching to express-postgres-starter_postgres_1, express-postgres-starter_app_1
postgres_1  | 2019-10-16 14:54:11.649 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2019-10-16 14:54:11.649 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2019-10-16 14:54:11.864 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2019-10-16 14:54:12.174 UTC [22] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-10-16 14:40:22 UTC
postgres_1  | 2019-10-16 14:54:12.250 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
app_1       | 
app_1       | > express-postgres-starter@1.0.0 dev /app
app_1       | > nodemon ./start.js
app_1       | 
app_1       | [nodemon] 1.19.3
app_1       | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
app_1       | [nodemon] watching dir(s): *.*
app_1       | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
app_1       | [nodemon] starting `node ./start.js`
app_1       | before cookie parser
app_1       | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
app_1       |     throw err;
app_1       |     ^
app_1       | 
app_1       | Error: Cannot find module 'cookie-parser'
app_1       |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
app_1       |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
app_1       |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
app_1       |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
app_1       |     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/index.js:12:22)
app_1       |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
app_1       |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
app_1       |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
app_1       |     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
app_1       |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
app_1       | [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

And when I run `docker-compose build` it fails like this:

```
me@thecomputer:~/thepath$ docker-compose build
postgres uses an image, skipping
Building app
Step 1/7 : FROM node:10
 ---> 636ef87129d6
Step 2/7 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5725fbf13d4e
Step 3/7 : COPY ./package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> da0c91be40e9
Step 4/7 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in f16814bb79d3
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "src/utils" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-10-16T15_05_50_411Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Which makes me think that the install command does not manage to install packages properly, so basically the node process can't find `cookie-parser` because it failed to install local packages before getting to the `cookie-parser` installation.

All I need is just to be able to use local packages, since it's my preferred way of organizing code within my application. Thanks! :)

Comment: add this to your package.json `"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "core-js": "^2.6.5",
  }`check this issue https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/500,

Comment: @Adiii those modules are needed when compilation to a previous javascript version is needed, right? There is no code that needs to be compiled in my codebase, the node.js version in the docker-compose.yaml can handle all the syntax. Anyways I tried but the error persists. Thanks for replying!

Comment: it worked here just fine: `git clone https://github.com/HugoDF/express-postgres-starter.git`, `cd express-postgres-starter`, `docker-compose up`. I can see correct response in browser.

Comment: @ahwayakchih yes that repository does not have local modules, mine has two :)

Comment: well, if you want additional modules, try to change `docker-compose.yml` command for node.js part, so it looks something like `npm install && npm run dev`.

Comment: or you can change `volumes` to use local directory instead of "virtual" one for installed modules. For example, instead of `- /app/node_modules`, use `- ./node_modules:/app/node_modules`. Just remember to create local `node_modules` first, outside of docker, otherwise it will create it as root and then npm will not be able to write there (at least not by default).

Comment: @ahwayakchih thanks, that got it working, is there a way I could avoid relying on running npm install in the actual project? This is one of those little quirks that sting in the development process, regardless of how simple they are

Comment: If you want to install/remove modules without too much work, i think it's best to map local `node_modules` directory instead of using "virtual" one. Anyway, to install/change modules, you can "join" active session from another terminal like this: `docker exec -it YOUR_SESSION_NAME /bin/sh`, where "YOUR_SESSION_NAME" is the name found by running `docker ps -a` command. It probably will be something like `docker_app_1`. In that separate terminal, you can run `npm install whatever`, end then simply use `exit` command to "logout" (no worry, your docker-composed session will keep running).

Comment: @ahwayakchih thanks a lot!